# Decorate function or object in JS

Tags: javascript, decorator

It seems impossible to decorate a single function or an object by the declarative decorator. I see that it is only possible for classes and properties. I use babel and receive a following error.

```sh
 Leading decorators must be attached to a class declaration (8:7)
```

The code is following.

```
function dec(func) {
  return function (a, b) {
    return a + b + 1
  }
}

@dec() function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

I will be pleased for any tip.

Comment: Decorators are in stage2 at the moment, and the initial proposal aims for them to be used on Classes, Class fields, Class methods and Class accessors. Potentially in the future support for function decorators might be available: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-decorators/blob/master/EXTENSIONS.md#function-decorators-and-annotations

Comment: Does a babel plugin exist? It has to. But I have not found it.